# need to call mysql_real_escape_string() twice

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-real-escape-string, magic-quotes-gpc

I have some user-input data that is put into a MySQL database (version 5.5.8 according to phpMyAdmin) - I find that `mysql_real_escape_string()` in my example below must be called twice or no backslashes get added to a user input text such as **"SHE'S A GREAT BOAT ISN'T SHE"**

The problem occurs when I try to write that type of "text string containing quotes" into my database -- the user input string is written to the database with *no backslashes* -- unless I call `mysql_real_escape_string()` twice.

I use phpMyAdmin to view the newly-written database record, and the user's text-string-with-quotes has NO ESCAPING on the quotes (no backslashes).   If I read that text string back out of the database, the quotes are not escaped, ie. I don't have to call `stripslashes()` to reverse the use of `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

The code is below.  When I call get_magic_quotes_gpc() it shows they are **disabled.**

My expectation was this:  if a user inputs a text string like **"SHE'S A GREAT BOAT ISN'T SHE"** -- and I then call `mysql_real_escape_string()` **one time** on that user input text, and write that to the database,  this  **one call** to `mysql_real_escape_string()` would create a text string that looks like this:

**\"SHE\'S A GREAT BOAT ISN\'T SHE\"**

But the text written to the database (see below) shows **no** escaping, just the original user-input text with all its unescaped quotes.

This is the PHP code that writes the user text string to the database:

```
// theUsersInputText contains "SHE'S A GREAT BOAT ISN'T SHE"
$theText = $_POST['theUsersInputText'];

$theDB = connectToDb();

  // THIS ALWAYS REPORTS THAT MAGIC QUOTES ARE DISABLED
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
echo "Magic quotes are enabled";
else
echo "Magic quotes are disabled";  

$theEscapedText =  mysql_real_escape_string($theText);
$newInsertQuery = "INSERT INTO " . "myDatabaseTable" 
        . " VALUES "
        . "('" . $theEscapedText . "')";
```

When I use phpMyAdmin to look at the database, NO SLASHES ARE IN THE TEXT STRING. And when retrieve this string from the database -- it looks like this:  **"SHE'S A GREAT BOAT ISN'T SHE"**

It makes me think I'm open to injection attack then.

So I modified the code above by adding a **second call** to `mysql_real_escape_string`, and now when I look at the database, FINALLY the text string looks like this:

**\"SHE\'S A GREAT BOAT ISN\'T SHE\"**

Here's the modified code:

```
$theText = $_POST['theUsersInputText'];

  // NEW LINE OF CODE HERE
$theStrangelyUnescapedText =  mysql_real_escape_string($theText);    

$theDB = connectToDb();

  // THIS ALWAYS REPORTS THAT MAGIC QUOTES ARE DISABLED
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
showAlertBox("Magic quotes are enabled");
else
showAlertBox("Magic quotes are disabled");  


$theFinallyEscapedText =  mysql_real_escape_string($theStrangelyUnescapedText);
$newInsertQuery = "INSERT INTO " . "myDatabaseTable" 
        . " VALUES "
        . "('" . $theFinallyEscapedText . . "')";
```

After the above, finally in phpMyAdmin, when I look at the just-written database record, the text looks like:

**\"SHE\'S A GREAT BOAT ISN\'T SHE\"**

Why do I have to call `mysql_real_escape_string()` twice here?

Comment: some one will point out you should stop using mysql_*

Comment: it's legacy code, or the alternatives would be taken up, but thanks.

Comment: you don't see the \ in the db, there is no need to call it twice. they are for character escaping, they are not stored

Comment: @CFHcoder: What's the output when you echo both the variables?

Comment: @Amal the first echo (after the 1st call to MRES) shows no backslashes, the second echo of the input text  (after the 2nd call to MRES) shows backslashes were added.

Comment: what is the name of your table and column, you are closing them betwen `\`table`\` and `\`columns`\` check that

Comment: there's nothing I can find anywhere to explain it -- I tried using mysqli_real_escape_string with the other mysqli_xxx functions and get the same result.  For now, my plan is to just accept the fact that I have to call _real_escape_string() twice to get the proper escaping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use a heredoc and output to a file to determine what effect, if any, my first call to mysql_real_escape_string() was having.  I used the following code -- the php variable "theTextWithManyQuotes" was read from user input, it was a text string such as
 "Isn't O'Malley's parents' children's "choices" atypical"

```
  $theTextWithManyQuotes = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userInput']);

  $html = <<<HEREDOC

  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <body>
    <textarea readonly name="adPreviewText" id="adPreviewText" rows="4" cols="60"
      style="border: none; border-style: none">$theTextWithManyQuotes</textarea>
  /body>
  </html>
HEREDOC;

file_put_contents("testfileonly", $html);
```

I then dumped the $html variable to a file by way of file_put_contents() and opened the "testfileonly" file -- and the backslashes were in fact present in the text.

My surmise is that when I build a mysql query string and it contains escaped text strings that were escaped by a single call to mysql_real_escape_string(), the database somehow 'hides' the backslashes so that they're not visible in phpMyAdmin when looking at the database record.

The fact that my heredoc's contents, when output to a file, shows that the backslashes are present, it proved to me that only a single call to mysql_real_escape_string() was required, and the mysql database is somehow not showing (or stripping?) the backslashes in the database records.  When the data is read back out of the database, no call to stripslashes() is required, the backslashes are not present in the text strings when read back out from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Written in this way

```
$theEscapedText =  mysql_real_escape_string($theText);
$newInsertQuery = "INSERT INTO `myDatabaseTable`  VALUES ('$theEscapedText')";
```

i get the query output

```
INSERT INTO `myDatabaseTable` VALUES ('\"SHE\'S A GREAT BOAT ISN\'T SHE\"')
```

the slashes is to make the query syntactically correct and try to avoid sql injection, in the db the query will stored the original text

```
"SHE'S A GREAT BOAT ISN'T SHE"
```

As side Note: Mysql_* extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

A useful link [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: when you say 'I get the query output' are you using echo to view the contents of the php variable $newInsertQuery?  I've previously done that and do not see slashes until the 2nd call to MRES.  Else how are you seeing the 'query output', what are you using when you say 'I get the query output' --?

Comment: echo $newInsertQuery; note that i changed the way that the query is in php

Comment: rats, so apparently the first time you call mysql_real_escape_string then you echo the resulting php variable, you see the backslashes.  Unfortunately my 1st call to MRES does not have that effect -- I have to call mysql_real_escape_string a 2nd time before the echo'd php variable has slashes in it.

Comment: you tried echo the post? to see what are getting in post? other side, and it seems some specific configuration of your server

Comment: My web server configuration is simply discarding the 1st call to mysql_real_escape_string, some setting somewhere I'm guessing. If I call MRES three times then echo the php variable, it's only showing a doubling, not a tripling, of backslashes.  I removed the extraneous concat operator, thanks, it was an error of simplifying the real code for this post, it's not in the production code.